# LinkedList Node Insertion

Tags: c++, list

I know this is seriously basic stuff, but I for the life of me can't seem to understand how I would go about doing this:

**Q:** Given the following struct definition for a Node:

```
struct Node
{
     int value;
     Node* next;
};
```

And given the declaration:

```
Node* head;
```

The following Linked List of Nodes has been constructed, with the head pointer assigned to the Node object 3:

```
head ----> 3 ----> 9 ----> 34 ----> -5 ----> NULL
```

Write a single C++ statement that will store the value 34 in the 3rd Node in the variable result:

`int result =`

Where would be a good place to start? Is this asking me to add an element to the list, or is it adding an entirely new node to the list? So confused!!

Comment: It's asking you to read the 3rd node and store value in `result`.

Comment: a good start would be starting by head, and follow the next pointers until you are at the correct position. then you should but the value into the variable result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`head->next->next` will point to the third node in the linked list.
So,

`int result = head->next->next->data;`

will store the value in the third node in the list.

The question is asking you to read the third node and store it's value in result.

Comment: Pardon me sir but please mind you semicolon. We're doing C++ after all. Sorry, couldn't resist :-)

Comment: So it's not asking me to insert anything. Alright, that's how I was reading it, but I was confused because it seemed like 34 was already there. What if the list were huge, and I wanted a value that was 300th in line or so. Is there a better way than head->next->next->next->next->next->next->next->next etc...

Comment: then you should use a loop ;)

Comment: @JeffreyDilley Use some loop e. g. for.

Comment: Right, I figured a loop would work, but implimentation is what I'm hung up on. I use loops to iterate through a set of numbers, not a set of commands, such as ->next.

Comment: @JanKorous, why is it that you use -> data. I've never seen that working with lists/nodes. Is that common for c++? And what purpose does it serve?Couldn't I just go with head->next->next and have the value 34 there? Or does it merely point to that value, and data actually retrieves it and assigns the value to result?

Comment: @Thomas do you know??

Comment: @JanKorous I did edit it and added the semi colon. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Linked lists employ a chain concept, where each chain-link along the **entire** length of the chain is connected at the **front** of each link.

People represent this in various ways. One example is:

```
struct Node {
    int value;
    Node* front;
};
```

Or:

```
struct Node {
    int value;
    Node* next;
};
```

When you establish the head of a linked list, you are creating the first node in the chain:

```
Node* head;
head = NULL; // this is an empty linked list
```

Whenever you want to add a node (or "link") to the chain, you pass along the new node to "Head", which keeps track of the chain:

```
void newNode(int value, Node* head)
{
    Node *node;
    node = new Node*; // or (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node->value = value;
    node->next = head;
    head = node;
}
```

Using this concept, you can add any number of links to your chain. Thomas and warun have good examples of this.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Since this is singly-linked list I am rather confused that it should be connected at the front and at the back. What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry Jan, I was thinking of a queue in my head for a minute. Editing this :)

Answer (score 1):

example for a loop.

```
Node* temp = head;
int number = 300; //the place you are looking for
if(temp)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; i< number && temp->next != nullptr ;i++)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    if(i == 300)
    {
        //found you value;
        result = temp->value;
    }
}
```